How to get access and refresh token from twitter v2 API
My end goal is to create an X(Twitter) bot.
Now I am trying to connect to Twitter v2 API.
Below is my code. I can get an authorization code in the redirect url. But I want the access & refresh token. What should I do?
Do I need to explicitly call token uri or will spring boot oauth2 client do it for me?
pom.xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

application.yml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          twitter:
            provider: twitter
            client-id: aaaa
            client-secret: sssss
            client-authentication-method: none
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/authCode"
            scope: tweet.read,tweet.write,offline.access
        provider:
          twitter:
            authorizationUri: https://twitter.com/i/oauth2/authorize
            tokenUri: https://api.twitter.com/2/oauth2/token

and SecurityConfig.java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/","/authCode").permitAll();
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .oauth2Login(withDefaults())
                .build();
    }
}

